# Reading Vectorized JSON Data in an R data frame

Tags: r, json

### Problem

I have a dataset with a column of json data:

| id | reply_to |
| --- | --- |
| 1.5946E+18 | [{'screen_name': '3sidedstory', 'name': '3sidedstory ', 'id': '1170447582272708614'}] |
| 1.5946E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'EITC_Official', 'name': ' Inside The Classroom', 'id': '1520028377457078275'}] |
| 1.5945E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'againstgrmrs', 'name': 'Gays Against Groomers', 'id': '1533857787486388226'}] |
| 1.5945E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'stillgray', 'name': 'Ian Miles Cheong', 'id': '16106584'}] |
| 1.5944E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'chadfelixg', 'name': 'Chad Felix Greene', 'id': '17626317'}] |
| 1.5944E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'CBSNewsPress', 'name': 'CBS News PR', 'id': '331211313'}] |
| 1.5943E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'PinkNews', 'name': 'PinkNews', 'id': '27987687'}] |
| 1.5941E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'Annakhait', 'name': 'Anna Khait', 'id': '534881613'}, {'screen_name': 'realDonaldTrump', 'name': 'Donald J. Trump', 'id': '25073877'}, {'screen_name': 'elonmusk', 'name': 'Elon Musk', 'id': '44196397'}] |
| 1.5938E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'MSNBC', 'name': 'MSNBC', 'id': '2836421'}, {'screen_name': 'thereidout', 'name': 'The ReidOut', 'id': '205864193'}] |
| 1.5937E+18 | [{'screen_name': 'MattWalshBlog', 'name': 'Matt Walsh', 'id': '1500129642'}, {'screen_name': 'MarkDavis', 'name': 'Mark Davis', 'id': '25916881'}] |

When I try to read that column, I get errors:

```r
tweets %>% mutate(reply2 = fromJSON(reply_to))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This little code snippet uses `jsonlite`, but I’ve tried other JSON readers and always get the same error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:! Problem while computing `reply2 = jsonlite::fromJSON(reply_to)`.Caused by error:! lexical error: invalid char in json text.                                     [{'screen_name': '3sidedstory', '                     (right here) ------^
```

### Wrinkle

If I extract any one of the cells’ content and save just that text as a separate json file, I can import & manipulate that data without any problem.

### Question

How can I vectorize reading this column and saving it into the original data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: Using purrr::map gives the same error. I'm not sure how to show the `dput` of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm not sure what the expected output is, but we could define our own function to parse the json text and pull out relavent info:

```r
library(tidyverse)

json_2_list <- function(json_text){
  x <- str_extract_all(json_text, "'.*?':\\s'.*?'") |>
    map(\(x) gsub("'", "", x) |> str_split(":")) 

  y <- map(x, \(y) map(y, \(z) str_trim(z[2]))) 
  z <- map(x, \(y) map(y, \(z) z[1]))
  
  map2(y, z, \(a,b) set_names(a, b))
}

df1 |>
  rename(input_id = id) |>
  mutate(reply2 = json_2_list(reply_to)) |>
  unnest_longer(reply2)|>
  group_by(input_id, reply2_id) |>
  mutate(grp = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = reply2_id, values_from = reply2)  |>
  select(-grp, -reply_to)
#> # A tibble: 14 x 4
#> # Groups:   input_id [7]
#>    input_id screen_name     name                    id                 
#>       <dbl> <chr>           <chr>                   <chr>              
#>  1  1.59e18 3sidedstory     3sidedstory ????        1170447582272708614
#>  2  1.59e18 EITC_Official   ?? Inside The Classroom 1520028377457078275
#>  3  1.59e18 againstgrmrs    Gays Against Groomers   1533857787486388226
#>  4  1.59e18 stillgray       Ian Miles Cheong        16106584           
#>  5  1.59e18 chadfelixg      Chad Felix Greene       17626317           
#>  6  1.59e18 CBSNewsPress    CBS News PR             331211313          
#>  7  1.59e18 PinkNews        PinkNews                27987687           
#>  8  1.59e18 Annakhait       Anna Khait              534881613          
#>  9  1.59e18 realDonaldTrump Donald J. Trump         25073877           
#> 10  1.59e18 elonmusk        Elon Musk               44196397           
#> 11  1.59e18 MSNBC           MSNBC                   2836421            
#> 12  1.59e18 thereidout      The ReidOut             205864193          
#> 13  1.59e18 MattWalshBlog   Matt Walsh              1500129642         
#> 14  1.59e18 MarkDavis       Mark Davis              25916881
```

And the data used:

```r
df1 <- tribble(~id, ~reply_to,
1.5946E+18, "[{'screen_name': '3sidedstory', 'name': '3sidedstory ????', 'id': '1170447582272708614'}]",
1.5946E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'EITC_Official', 'name': '?? Inside The Classroom', 'id': '1520028377457078275'}]",
1.5945E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'againstgrmrs', 'name': 'Gays Against Groomers', 'id': '1533857787486388226'}]",
1.5945E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'stillgray', 'name': 'Ian Miles Cheong', 'id': '16106584'}]",
1.5944E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'chadfelixg', 'name': 'Chad Felix Greene', 'id': '17626317'}]",
1.5944E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'CBSNewsPress', 'name': 'CBS News PR', 'id': '331211313'}]",
1.5943E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'PinkNews', 'name': 'PinkNews', 'id': '27987687'}]",
1.5941E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'Annakhait', 'name': 'Anna Khait', 'id': '534881613'}, {'screen_name': 'realDonaldTrump', 'name': 'Donald J. Trump', 'id': '25073877'}, {'screen_name': 'elonmusk', 'name': 'Elon Musk', 'id': '44196397'}]",
1.5938E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'MSNBC', 'name': 'MSNBC', 'id': '2836421'}, {'screen_name': 'thereidout', 'name': 'The ReidOut', 'id': '205864193'}]",
1.5937E+18, "[{'screen_name': 'MattWalshBlog', 'name': 'Matt Walsh', 'id': '1500129642'}, {'screen_name': 'MarkDavis', 'name': 'Mark Davis', 'id': '25916881'}]")
```

Comment: that's the expected output. thanks!

Comment: btw, this forces me to learn some new stuff from R 4.1. Bonus points.